# Nuxt/Jest - Syntax Error: Unexpected token {

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

I have installed the Vue Test tools, installed Jest and have a test case just to verify that the vue instance works.

My test looks like the following

```
/* global describe, test, expect */
/* eslint no-undef: "error" */
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Logo from '@/components/Logo';

describe('Logo', ()=> {
test('is a vue instance', () => {
const wrapper = mount(Logo)
expect(wrapper.vm).toBeTruthy()
});
});
```

I run it using `npm run test` and get the following error

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
Syntax error: Unexpected token {

(with an carrot pointing to the { in front of { mount }
```

Any ideas?

***** Editing to add my jest.config.js ****

```
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
   '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
   '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
   '^vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
 }, 
 moduleFileExtentions: ['js', 'vue', 'json'],
 testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/dist/', '/node_modules/'], 
 transform: {
   '^.+\\.js$' : 'babel-jest',
   '.*\\.(vue)$' : 'vue-jest'
 }, 
collectCoverage: true, 
collectCoverageFrom: [
  '<rootDir>/components/**/*.vue', 
   '<rootDir>/pages/**/*.vue'
 ]
}
```

Comment: could you post the script "test" from your package.json?

Comment: Sure it's just "test": "jest"

Comment: try with: `"test": "vue-cli-service test:unit"`

Comment: I edited to add my jest.config.js above

running that command gives me 
sh: vue-cli-service: command not found

Is that something I need to add if I am doing NuxtJs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I needed to add '@babel/preset-env' to my presets in my babel.config

I'm now getting errors related to Vuetify but for this issue that fixed the problem. Ill create a new question for the other issue.